# pandas histogram plot error: ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 0, not 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, histogram

I am drawing a histogram of a column from pandas data frame:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
df.hist(column='column_A', bins = 100)
```

but got the following errors:

```
     62                     raise ValueError(
     63                         "num must be 1 <= num <= {maxn}, not {num}".format(
---> 64                             maxn=rows*cols, num=num))
     65                 self._subplotspec = GridSpec(rows, cols)[int(num) - 1]
     66                 # num - 1 for converting from MATLAB to python indexing

ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 0, not 1
```

Does anyone know what this error mean? Thanks!

Comment: what is the dtype of `column_A` - is it a numeric dtype?

Comment: @MaxU: You are right. I forgot to convert the type. Thanks for the reminder. works now

Comment: can you tell me more clearly how you solved your problem? I have the same problem with this: `yearly_average[:10].hist(column='year')`

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

The problem you encounter arises when `column_A` does not contain numeric data. As you can see in the excerpt from `pandas.plotting._core` below, the numeric data is essential to make the function `hist_frame` (which you call by `DataFrame.hist()`) work correctly.

```py
def hist_frame(data, column=None, by=None, grid=True, xlabelsize=None,
               xrot=None, ylabelsize=None, yrot=None, ax=None, sharex=False,
               sharey=False, figsize=None, layout=None, bins=10, **kwds):
    # skipping part of the code
    # ...
    if column is not None:
        if not isinstance(column, (list, np.ndarray, Index)):
            column = [column]
        data = data[column]
    data = data._get_numeric_data()  # there is no numeric data in the column
    naxes = len(data.columns)  # so the number of axes becomes 0
    # naxes is passed to the subplot generating function as 0 and later determines the number of columns as 0
    fig, axes = _subplots(naxes=naxes, ax=ax, squeeze=False,
                          sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey, figsize=figsize,
                          layout=layout)
    # skipping the rest of the code
    # ...
```

---

## Solution

1. If your problem is to represent *numeric* data (but not of **numeric dtype** *yet*) with a histogram, you need to cast your data to numeric, either with `pd.to_numeric` or `df.astype(a_selected_numeric_dtype)`, e.g. `'float64'`, and then proceed with your code.
2. If your problem is to represent *non-numeric* data in *one column* with a histogram, you can call the function `hist_series` with the following line: `df['column_A'].hist(bins=100)`.
3. If your problem is to represent *non-numeric* data in *many columns* with a histogram, you may resort to a handful options:

   - Use `matplotlib` and create subplots and histograms directly
   - Update pandas at least to version `0.25`

Answer (score -1):

usually is 0

```
mta['penn'] = [mta_bystation[mta_bystation.STATION == "34 ST-PENN STA"], 'Penn Station']
mta['grdcntrl'] = [mta_bystation[mta_bystation.STATION == "GRD CNTRL-42 ST"], 'Grand Central']
mta['heraldsq'] = [mta_bystation[mta_bystation.STATION == "34 ST-HERALD SQ"], 'Herald Sq']
mta['23rd'] = [mta_bystation[mta_bystation.STATION == "23 ST"], '23rd St']
#mta['portauth'] = [mta_bystation[mta_bystation.STATION == "42 ST-PORT AUTH"], 'Port Auth']
#mta['unionsq'] = [mta_bystation[mta_bystation.STATION == "14 ST-UNION SQ"], 'Union Sq']
mta['timessq'] = [mta_bystation[mta_bystation.STATION == "TIMES SQ-42 ST"], 'Ti
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? Your answer makes no sense as it currently stands.