# Pandas matplotlib: event count histogram

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data frame

```
    event_time                   day
0   2017-06-08 13:35:56.41     2017-06-08
1   2017-06-08 13:35:24.62     2017-06-08
2   2017-06-14 17:44:32.49     2017-06-14
3   2017-06-08 14:40:40.79     2017-06-08
4   2017-06-08 13:40:04.54     2017-06-08
```

I then tried to plot a histogram as event count per day like:

```
%matplotlib notebook
my_df.hist(column = 'day')
```

but got the error below. Any idea what I did wrong and how do I get a proper event count histogram? Thanks!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-2a39070c9855> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib notebook')
----> 2 my_df.hist(column = 'day')

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in hist_frame(data, column, by, grid, xlabelsize, xrot, ylabelsize, yrot, ax, sharex, sharey, figsize, layout, bins, **kwds)
   2919     fig, axes = _subplots(naxes=naxes, ax=ax, squeeze=False,
   2920                           sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey, figsize=figsize,
-> 2921                           layout=layout)
   2922     _axes = _flatten(axes)
   2923 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _subplots(naxes, sharex, sharey, squeeze, subplot_kw, ax, layout, layout_type, **fig_kw)
   3412 
   3413     # Create first subplot separately, so we can share it if requested
-> 3414     ax0 = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, 1, **subplot_kw)
   3415 
   3416     if sharex:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1018                     self._axstack.remove(ax)
   1019 
-> 1020             a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1021 
   1022         self._axstack.add(key, a)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
     62                     raise ValueError(
     63                         "num must be 1 <= num <= {maxn}, not {num}".format(
---> 64                             maxn=rows*cols, num=num))
     65                 self._subplotspec = GridSpec(rows, cols)[int(num) - 1]
     66                 # num - 1 for converting from MATLAB to python indexing

ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 0, not 1
```

Comment: Did you ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581525/pandas-histogram-plot-error-valueerror-num-must-be-1-num-0-not-1) a year ago?  `column` must be a numeric dtype.

Comment: It's pretty close to the old question, but that one never got answered and this one does contain more info (column type) so I think it's a reasonable question (especially as a 9 month old question is extremely unlikely to get answered at this point)

Comment: This works for me:  `df['day'].hist()`.  I don't know why it works but yours doesn't. I'd expect them to be equivalent.